# Understanding ACF function

Tags: autocorrelation

I am working on a data with multiple measurements. And I wanted to know if there exists AR correlation. So I created the ACF graph acf(Response,Time) but I don't understand which of the 4 graph that I should look at and how to interpret them.
As long as I know, the blue dash line refers to the 95% confidence limit of correlation that are caused by white noise. Would it be right if I interpret the first graph as the following?

1) At lag=1 the ACF is slightly above the blue dash line so there exist a AR1 relationship?
[image]